# I'm about to be homeless

Tags: home

I'm not sure that this question really belongs here; I couldn't find an SE site that seemed to fit this question. I apologize if there is a better place for this.

So recent events have led to my wife having a (temporary) restraining order against me. I'm not allowed to go home (to our apartment), see my wife or our daughter. My wife has contacted the leasing office and told them that she's moved out. Given that I can't afford the rent at the apartment on my own, I'm going to have to break the lease.

Now I have a full time job that nets me about $2000 after deductions, but this is not enough to afford an apartment (plus utilities, groceries, etc) in a neighborhood that isn't crawling with gang members.

I'm currently staying with the one family member that I have that lives in this state, and he just sold his house. Within the next few weeks, I'll probably be living in my car.

My question is as follows: What options do I have for affordable living in these circumstances? I currently live in Santa Clarita, just north of Los Angeles, California.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your situation; unfortunately, the housing options available to resolve this type of issue are far outside the scope of *this* site. Unfortunately, I don't think we have a site to handle this type of outreach or discussion. This type of issue is a bit outside of what we traditionally consider part of our Q&A ecosystem. But I wish you the best of luck.